# Knockout array binding works only once

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working on a file upload code which at the moment works only in Chrome and Firefox. It allows users to drag and drop files which get uploaded. The upload progress is shown in a grid.

Here is the html

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" action="home/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
    <div id="filedrag">Drop files here</div>
    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton">Upload Files</button>
</form>

<table class="datatable" data-bind="visible:files().length>0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Upload progress</th>
            <th>Progress bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:files">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:status"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:percentUploaded"></td>
            <td>
              <progress max="100" data-bind="attr: {value:percentUploaded}"></progress>
              <span data-bind="text:$root.files().length"></span></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data.files, null, 2)"></pre>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
var File = function (f) {
    this.name = f.name;
    this.type = f.type;
    this.size = f.size;
    this.lastModified = f.lastModifiedDate.toDateString();
    this.status = ko.observable(f.status);
    this.percentUploaded = ko.observable(0);
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this,
      maxFileSize = 5000000,
      onFileSelecting = function (e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
          e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
      },
    onFileSelected = function (e) {
        onFileSelecting(e);// cancel event and hover styling
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var validationResult = validate(f);
            f.status = validationResult || 'Uploading';
            self.addFile(f);
            uploadFile(f);
        }
    },
    validate = function (f) {
        if (f.size > maxFileSize)
            return 'Too large, should be less than 5MB';
        if (f.type.indexOf("text") != 0)
            return 'Wrong file type';
    },
    uploadFile = function (f) {
        var file = self.files()[0];

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("files", f, f.name);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
            file.status("Uploaded " + parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + "%");
            file.percentUploaded(parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100));
        }, false);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                file.status((xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure"));
            }
        };

        xhr.open("POST", $("#fileUploadForm")[0].action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
        xhr.send(fd);
    };

    self.files = ko.observableArray();
    self.addFile = function (f) { self.files.unshift(new File(f)); };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            var fileSelector = $("#fileselect"),
              fileDragArea = $("#filedrag"),
              submitButton = $("#submitbutton");

            fileSelector.change(onFileSelected);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (xhr.upload) {
                filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", onFileSelecting, false);
                filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", onFileSelecting, false);
                filedrag.addEventListener("drop", onFileSelected, false);
                filedrag.style.display = "block";
                submitbutton.style.display = "none";
                fileSelector.hide();
            }
        }
    });
};

var model = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

When I drag and drop a set of files, everything works fine. However, when I drag and drop another set, the files array gets updated, but the grid does not show additional rows.

However, everything works fine when I take out this piece of HTML5 mark up:

```
<progress max="100" data-bind="attr: {value:percentUploaded}"></progress>
```

I have created the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9aJtG/1) but it has other problems - 1) The drag and drop on fiddle just opens up the file (not sure why) 2) on dropping the files the files get submitted, but there is no server side code which can work with JSFiddle form posting

I have tried with progress bar in another example, which does not have this problem http://jsfiddle.net/bxfXd/800/

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: did you set the progress bar back to 0?

Comment: Your jsFiddle threw an error for me (in Chrome) - you need to bind to `$parent.incrementPctCounter` on your + buttons.  Update here: http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/bxfXd/797/

Comment: Sorry, my last change wasn't updated in JSFiddle. I have changed the link now to working code.

Comment: @Gabber - Wouldn't data-bind="attr: {value:percentUploaded} set the progress bar to whatever value it has. Note: each row in the grid has a progress bar, its not a common bar for everything.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle that reproduces your problem but is representative of the code you have? Giving us code that isn't the same as your problem doesn't really help us understand the problem.

Comment: I have created the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9aJtG/1/) but it has other problems - 1) The drag and drop on fiddle just opens up the file (not sure why) 2) on dropping the files the files get submitted, but there is no server side code which can work with JSFiddle form posting